# Firefox: Can I use a relative path in the BASE tag?

Tags: html, firefox, relative-path, radix

I have a little web project where I have many pages and an index/ToC file. The toc file is at the root of my project in `toc.html`. The pages are spread over a couple of subdirectories and include the toc with an `iframe`.

The project doesn't need a web server, so I can create the HTML in a directory and browse it in my browser. The problem is that I'm running into XSS issues when JavaScript from the `toc.html` wants to call a function in a page (violation of the same origin policy).

So I added `base` tags in the header with a relative URL to the directory in which `toc.html`. This works for Konqueror but in Firefox, I have to use absolute paths or the toc won't even display :( Here is an example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<base href="../" target="_top" />
<title>Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="toc" frameborder="0" src="toc.html">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This is file is in a subdirectory `page`. Firefox won't even load it, saying that it can't find `page/toc.html`.

Is there a workaround? I would really like to avoid absolute paths in my export to keep it the same everywhere (locally and when I upload it on the web server later).

Comment: I have the same problem right now. It seems Firefox won't take into account `<base>` tags that point to relative paths. Sadly enough, the first Google result on the matter is this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HTML4, `<base>` needs an [absolute URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4). However, since HTML5 now has widespread support, it should be mentioned that the [HTML5 `<base>` tag accepts an URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#the-base-element), which can be either absolute or relative; this effectively means that you can now use a relative path instead of an absolute URI.